# Newtonsoft Serialization throws InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, json, serialization

We are trying to figure out how to solve this `InvalidCastException`.

[image]

```
"ExceptionType": "System.InvalidCastException",
"StackTrace": "  at ...Objects.Patient.Equals(Object obj) in 
 at System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer`1.Equals(T x, T y)\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Contains(T item)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CheckForCircularReference
```

And in fact we found a similar post from the past with this code which also throws the same exception. And to reproduce it, we put in inside a simple `WinForm` :

```
private void buttonJsonSerializer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fixture = new Fixture
    {
        Name = "Fixture Name",
        participant = new Participant { Name = "Participant Name"}
    };

    fixture.participant = new Participant();            

    var writer = new StringWriter(new StringBuilder());
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
    serializer.Serialize(writer, fixture);
    string output = writer.ToString();

}

public class Fixture
{
    public string Name { get; set; }            
    public Participant participant { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var fixture = (Fixture)obj; // *** THROWS CAST EXCEPTION ***

        return fixture.Name == Name;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class Participant
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var participant = (Participant)obj;

        return participant.Name == Name;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

One of questions that came up was: does it have anything to do with the `Newtonsoft` library ?

And also, using `var fixture = obj as Fixture` is not what we are looking to do in this case, as it will simply return null.

Comment: Just fix your Equals implementation. It should check if  obj is Patient and if not - should return false. As is your implementation is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can't just assume argument of `Fixture::Equals` will always be a `Fixture`:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj is Fixture fixture)
    {
        return fixture.Name == Name;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And, you need to do the same for `Participant::Equals`:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj is Participant participant)
    {
        return participant.Name == Name;
    }

    return false;
}
```

> One of questions that came up was: does it have anything to do with the `Newtonsoft` library ?

It does:

> at UserQuery.Fixture.Equals(Object obj)    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer`1.Equals(T x, T y)
>
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Contains(T item)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CheckForCircularReference(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonProperty property, JsonContract contract,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object&
>   memberValue)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object
>   value)    at UserQuery.Main()    at
>   LINQPad.ExecutionModel.ClrQueryRunner.Run()    at
>   LINQPad.ExecutionModel.Server.RunQuery(QueryRunner runner)    at
>   LINQPad.ExecutionModel.Server.StartQuery(QueryRunner runner)    at
>   LINQPad.ExecutionModel.Server.<>c__DisplayClass152_0.b__0()
>   at LINQPad.ExecutionModel.Server.SingleThreadExecuter.Work()    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

`JsonSerializerInternalWriter::CheckForCircularReference` is calling `Equals` for circular reference.

Comment: Indeed this is due to the circular reference check.  For confirmation see [Object reference equality should be used when checking for circular references #401](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/401) where James Newton-King confirms that circular reference checking via `object.Equals()` is the intended behavior: *I prefer the current behavior which lets devs customize logic by overriding Equals.*